# Data points are not moving on the X Axis Scatter Plot in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013, excel-charts

I have an excel scatter plot which is working for the Y axis but not the X Axis.  If I change the Y values the data point moves accordingly.  However, the X axis seems to be fixed in positions.  The closest thing I can identify to logic is that the first number in the series is the X axis as 1, the next is 2, 3, 4, and so on

I would like (5.6,3) to show up at (5.6,3) not (1,3) because it's the first in the series.

Example for X axis theory:

```
Series 
X ------ Y ------ graph placement
.6 ----- 3 ------ (1,3)
1.2 ---- 3.4 ---- (2,3.4)
.8 ----- 5.2 ---- (3,5.2)
```

notice the X coordinates 1,2,3 are moving sequential with their placement in the series.

Example for Y axis working:

(1.333,1) is placed at (3,1) on the plot.  If I change it to (1.333,2) then it goes to (3,2).  The X Axis changes do not move the point.

[image: X Axis not changing]

Comment: Scatter Plot? I think you need a X-Y plot

Comment: @pnuts it doesn't appear to be working because the (X,Y) are the labels on the plot.  So it doesn't make sense when the X axis is 1.333 and shows up at 3.

Comment: @chrisneilsen what chart is that in Excel?  I took selected X Y Scatter and picked the first one.  What chart is the X-Y plot?

Comment: @pnuts I highlighted that data and selected NUMBER, as well as adjusted the number of decimals places to confirm it's a number.  Is there more I can do to confirm it's a number?

Comment: @pnuts I sum'd them and got a value

Comment: for select data:  ='TIME Model'!$R$4:$S$19  that encompasses both X and Y is that incorrect?  I have a feeling it could be here.

Comment: @pnuts yes it was the right number when I did =1*1.333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give up. On the right is a chart that I think represents what you are seeing, driven by the data as shown *which includes a single inverted comma I prefixed `1.333` with*. On the left I overlaid an image of the chart I see without that inverted comma - and I think represents what you want:

[image: SO34275941 example]

Comment: I figured it out.  The issue was in my formula I had if N/A then "" and conditional formatting to make it disappear, by having a non numeric ANYWHERE in the dataset it made the chart act weird.